# Storing variable names in list

Tags: python

I have the following the list:

```
lst_gws = ["gw1", "gw2", "gw3"]

gw1 = ["gw1-123", "gw1-234"]
gw2 = ["gw2-445", "gw2-332"]
gw3 = ["gw3-257", "gw3-321"]
```

Is it possible to loop through the list and print out the value of each of them, something like:

```
for i in lst_gws:
    print i
```

but printing the actual value and not the name.

Comment: If you ever find yourself storing strings which correspond to variable names, consider storing them in a dict instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
for i in lst_gws:
    print(locals()[i])
```

which would print them out as intended (`locals()` allows you to access any local variables):

```
>>> lst_gws = ["gw1", "gw2", "gw3"]
>>>
>>> gw1 = ["gw1-123", "gw1-234"]
>>> gw2 = ["gw2-445", "gw2-332"]
>>> gw3 = ["gw3-257", "gw3-321"]
>>> for i in lst_gws:
...     print(locals()[i])
...
['gw1-123', 'gw1-234']
['gw2-445', 'gw2-332']
['gw3-257', 'gw3-321']
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a dict?

```
lst_gws = {
    "gw1" : ["gw1-123", "gw1-234"],
    "gw2" : ["gw2-445", "gw2-332"],
    "gw3" : ["gw3-257", "gw3-321"],
}

for name in lst_gws:
    print lst_gws[name]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the local and global variable dictionary with `locals()` and `globals()`.

They are dictionaries where the key is the name of the variable and the value is its value...

```py
x = 3
y = 2
z = [1, 2, 3]
vars = ["x", "y", "z"]

for name in vars:
    print(locals()[name])
```